# Placing imageview on top of mapfragment/ mapview

Tags: java, android, google-maps, imageview

I want to place an imageview on top of  mapview/mapfragment. I have successfully placed the imageview, but there is a gap on the left and right of the screen. I want the imageview to completely cover the mapview. The resolution of the image used is 720x1280.

**The layout:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/sphere_background" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**The output:**

[image: Output]

**Please tell me a way by which the imageview will completely cover the map from left to right.**

Comment: you could play around with the scaleType, but i would suggest u to use a 9patch image, with a centered circle and a border which is scaleable so it feits ur needs on all screen sizes

Answer (score 0):

Add ImageView in android:scaleType="fitXY". Eg.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/sphere_background" />
```